# how to delete listview item by the name in the sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor

So, I wan't to delete my listview item on which the delete button is Located. Right now, my first Item gets deleted when i press the button. Can anybody help me?

**Locatie**

```
package com.buysse.roan.findyourstuff;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Locatie extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener {


    private Button buttonSave;
    private Button buttonDelete;
    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextLocation;
    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);





    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locatie);
        try{filList();
            List<Item> list = db.getAllItems();}
        catch( IndexOutOfBoundsException e){ System.out.println("caught");}
        //add all items to list
        //if(i>0){
        //filList();
        //List<Item> list = db.getAllItems();
        //db.deleteItem(list.get(0));}

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         *
         */

        //buttonpress
        buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddUser);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLocation);











       // add item

        // get all items


        // get all items

       //db.getAllItems();

        ///new activity remove



//toolbar

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.locatie, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //change links
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_Locatie) {
            Intent Locatie = new Intent(this, Locatie.class);
            startActivity(Locatie);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_objects) {
            Intent Object = new Intent(this, Object.class);
            startActivity(Object);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }


// onclick add to array + refresh list
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonAddUser) {
            db.addItem(new Item(editTextName.getText().toString(), editTextLocation.getText().toString()));

            /////Make Method
            try{filList();}
            catch( IndexOutOfBoundsException e){ System.out.println("caught");}
        }
    }

        public void filList(){
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, db.getAllItems());
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

//list delete
   public void deleteItem (View view ){
       List<Item> list = db.getAllItems();
                ArrayList items = db.getAllItems();
                db.deleteItem(list.get(0));

      try{filList();}
      catch( IndexOutOfBoundsException e){ System.out.println("caught");}//
    }




}
```

**content_locatie**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.buysse.roan.findyourstuff.Locatie"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_locatie"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/textViewNameText"
                android:id="@+id/textViewName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextName" />

        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonAddUser"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonAddText"
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddUser"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editTextLocation"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editTextLocation" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textViewLocation"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextLocation"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/textViewLocation"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextLocation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewLocation"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewLocation" />
```

**row** Custom layout listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Study cursors"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Location"
            android:layout_width="388dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_weight="0.07"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="deleteItem"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Sqlitehelper** + Method to delete in Locatie (was asked)

```
//list delete
   public void deleteItem (View view ){
       List<Item> list = db.getAllItems();
                ArrayList items = db.getAllItems();
                db.deleteItem(list.get(0));

      try{filList();}
      catch( IndexOutOfBoundsException e){ System.out.println("caught");}}}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
package com.buysse.roan.findyourstuff;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.lang.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by roanb on 10/08/2016.
 */
public class MySQLiteHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper { // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ItemDB";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SQL statement to create book table
        String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE items ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "name TEXT, "+
                "location TEXT )";

        // create items table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEM_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older items if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items");

        // create fresh items table
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    //sql statements

    // items table name
    private static final String TABLE_ITEMS = "items";

    // items Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_LOCATION};

    public void addItem (Item item){
        //for logging
        Log.d("addItem", item.toString());

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, item.getName()); // get name
        values.put(KEY_LOCATION, item.getLocation()); // get author

        // 3. insert
        db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, // table
                null, //nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

        // 4. close
        db.close();
    }

    public Item getItem(int id){

        // 1. get reference to readable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // 2. build query
        Cursor cursor =
                db.query(TABLE_ITEMS, // a. table
                        COLUMNS, // b. column names
                        " id = ?", // c. selections
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
                        null, // e. group by
                        null, // f. having
                        null, // g. order by
                        null); // h. limit

        // 3. if we got results get the first one
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        // 4. build item object
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        item.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        item.setLocation(cursor.getString(2));

        //log
        Log.d("geItem("+id+")", item.toString());

        // 5. return book
        return item;
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getAllItems() {
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

        // 1. build the query
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS;

        // 2. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        // 3. go over each rowl, build item and add it to list
        Item item = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                item = new Item();
                item.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                item.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                item.setLocation(cursor.getString(2));

                // Add item to items
                items.add(item);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        Log.d("getAllItems()", items.toString());

        // return items
        return items;
    }

    public int updateItem(Item item) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", item.getName()); // get title
        values.put("location", item.getLocation()); // get author

        // 3. updating rowl
        int i = db.update(TABLE_ITEMS, //table
                values, // column/value
                KEY_ID+" = ?", // selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(item.getId()) }); //selection args

        // 4. close
        db.close();

        return i;

    }

    public void deleteItem(Item item) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. delete
        db.delete(TABLE_ITEMS, //table name
                KEY_ID+" = ?",  // selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(item.getId()) }); //selections args

        // 3. close
        db.close();

        //log
        Log.d("deleteItem",item.toString());

    }




}
```

**MyAdapter**

```
private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList;

    public MyAdapterL(Context context, ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList) {

        super(context, R.layout.rowl, itemsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // 1. Create inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowl, parent, false);

        // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
        TextView labelView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Location);
        TextView valueView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Name);

        // 4. Set the text for textView
        labelView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getName());
        valueView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getLocation());

        // 5. retrn rowView
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code where you are trying to delete an item.

Comment: Added the code to delete an item

Comment: Add only needed code(in your case delete code and Listview code), not whole activity or project and try to avoid posting import statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the ListView class is not optimal, you should not be rebuilding the MyAdapter every time your data set changes.  You need to modify the backing data set, in your case the DB and then call:  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

As for the first data item always being deleted, I'd say it's because you always index item 0:

```
db.deleteItem(list.get(0));
```

You do not delete data from a ListView, you delete the data you want from the DB, using a SQL query and then update the adapter.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I wasn't clear enough. I know I allways delete the first item because of `db.deleteItem(list.get(0));` But I wan't to know how I can delete the item where the delete button is located by getting the name or the id and putting it in `db.deleteItem(list.get(0));` (or something like that.

Comment: I see now, you have a button on each ListView row, and you want a button press on that row to remove it.

Comment: I added the adapter class

Answer (score 0):

First thing, deleting data from a SQLite table using name is not an ideal method as long as the name is unique.

1. You can make a public function of deleteItem(id (or name)) in your activity.
2. Make the adapter a global variable.
3. Pass the activity in MyAdapter instead of context.
4. In getView of your adapter, setOnClickListener to the delete button. And in onClick call the deleteItem(id) function of your activity.
5. In the deleteItem(id) function add myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the end.

Thanks